# Why is a namespaced and nested route generating a URL which results in a routing error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
# config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
  namespace :product do
    resources :categories do
      resources :properties
    end
  end
end
```

`admin_product_category_properties_path(category)` generates the URL `http://localhost:3000/admin/product/categories/3/properties`. But this URL results in a routing error:

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant Admin::Product::PropertiesController
```

*It should be looking for Admin::Product::Categories::PropertiesController, why not?*

I know I can fix this by:

```
# config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
  namespace :product do
    resources :categories do
      resources :properties, :controller => 'categories/property_types'
    end
  end
end
```

But why do I need to do this, should Rails not already know the context?

---

Why the namespacing?

I have the following models:

```
product
product::category
product::category::property
```

The namespace is there because I have other models which have categories.

Answer (score 1):

Nested routes aren't the same as namespaced routes

```
# Nested routes
namespace :admin do
  namespace :product do
    resources :categories do
      resources :properties
    end
  end
end
# controller: Admin::Product::PropertiesController
# routes: /admin/product/categories/:category_id/properties
```

vs.

```
# Namespaced routes
namespace :admin do
  namespace :product do
    namespace :categories do
      resources :properties
    end
  end
end
# controller: Admin::Product::Categories::PropertiesController
# route: /admin/product/categories/properties
```

In the former example, you are specifying that all the properties are nested and accessed by a particular category (hence the `:category_id` in the route). In the latter example, you are just namespacing the properties by category (no `:category_id` is required).